# How to use End(xlToRight) and R1C1

Tags: excel, vba

I have a report that exports poorly.  I know that for every instance of "Currency" I need to go `R[-4]C[5]`, then `End(xlToRight).select`.  I have to use `End(xlToRight)` because the column the data is in changes throughout the report.  Below is what I'm currently doing and it's not working.  Any advice would be much appreciated.

```
Sub Test()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 9 To 40

    Cells(i, 3).FormulaR1C1 = "=if(R[-1]c[5]=""Currency:"",Range(R[-4]C[5].End(xlToRight)).select,r[-1]c)"
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: what is this? `=if(R[-1]c[5]=""Currency:"",Range(R[-4]C[5].End(xlToRight)).select,r[-1]c)` You are trying to enter this as a cell formula and I can't figure out what you are expecting it to do.

Comment: Is it... A formula that if the value in the cell up one row and over 5 columns is "Currency" then grab whatever is in the last column 4 rows above and if it is not "Currency" then grab the value one row up? o_0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm taking a blind stab at this one since it's difficult to discern what you are trying to do. I can say this much, you can't put VBA into a Cell's formula, so where you are trying `cells(i,3).formulaR1C1="=If(<crazy vba stuff in here>)"`... just isnt' going to work.

Picking apart what I believe you want that formula to do:

```
Sub Test()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 9 To 40        
         If Cells(i-1, 3+5).value = "Currency" then
              Cells(i, 3).value = Cells(i-4, 3+5).end(xlToRight).value
         Else
              Cells(i, 3).value = Cells(i-1, 3).value
         End if        
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: MY MAN!!!  I'm sorry for not being clearer with my question.  I'm a novice with VBA and you were able to bridge the gap.  I was trying to combine writing a typical formula with what I could find on the internet.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Can I add a follow up question?  How do I change the integer to go to the final row of data?

Comment: You can do something like `lastRow = Range("A999999").End(XlUp).Row()`

Comment: Man, you are awesome!  I've got one more question and I think I can pick this up.  I have multiple columns of data that need to updated using this same methodology.  How do I use the "If Cells(i-1, 3+5).value = "Currency" then" To then update multiple columns?  right now I'm updating Column C and need to update C:G, with varying cells above the "Currency" reference.  I'm learning so much from you!  THANK YOU

Comment: I just need an example of adding one more column to the Integer or If statement.  I can't find a good example.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following. The `IF` statement is just testing that one row up and 5 columns over there is a cell with "Currency" written in it. Are you wanting to test the next column over to see if it too has "Currency" or is that if the original column has "Currency" you want to update other cells besides `Cells(i, 3).value`

Comment: Currency always appears in the same column.  Based on every time it comes up, there is data above it a fixed number of cells.  I need to pull data to the right (using the end(xlToRight).value) of these cells.  There are multiple columns that I need to fill based on each occurrence of Currency.  I'm not sure if I need to use an IF statement or how exactly to fill out the other columns.

Comment: Once you find "Currency" then use cell references to get what you need. `Cells(i+1, 10).value` for example. Just stack those up until you have all of the value you need copied to wherever they need to go.

Comment: I tried something similar to that and it didn't work.  I'll try that.  Thanks so much man, I really appreciate it!  I'm trying to clean up someone else's file and this piece had me stumped.  I've got to use advanced filters after this, and thankfully I was able to figure that out.  Thanks again!